# How to implement Remember me functionality with DRF JWT?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am trying to implement a way for users to stay logged in my website using the JWT DRF implementation.

From the [documentation](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token) it's suggested that as soon as a token is expired there is no way to refresh them.

Given that a user might close their browser, my only two options are either having long-lived tokens or storing the username/password in localStorage, and both options seem insecure.

Is there a different way to achieve this? Alternatively is there a way to only have long-lived tokens depending on what a user wants (i.e chooses the remember me option)

Comment: I think you need to implement some custom middleware classes and check the token expiry in each request. If it going to expire soon, redirect to some page (i'm not sure redirection is possible) or raise some friendly exception

Comment: That's the normal workflow when the user is online, I am trying to figure a way to do that when the user is offline so they stay logged in when they return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, JWTs are intended to authenticate sessions short-term only, even with refresh. If you're designing for the browser, I suggest you use regular old [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) to keep users logged in longer-term (e.g. 30 days).

If you want to avoid cookies, you can use a combination of a short-lived and long-lived tokens using, for example, OAuth2 -- check out [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which integrates with DRF. The short-lived token authenticates the session just like a JWT, while the long-lived token (30-60 day lifetime) is used to get a short-lived token from your API and can be stored in localStorage.